# How do I move files in Finder Macbook from the "download folder" to another folder easily?

Tags: download, macbook, finder

Every time I download ordinary tekst folders I try to move them in Finder to the folder I want. I try it in several ways but most of them don't work.

DRAGGING-method
1) I try it by dragging them to a proper map by keeping the mouse button down and move all the files. But when I move the files to the "navigation column" and keep the pointer on the "Document Folder", the folder doesn't open automatically. Even if I keep the pointer a few seconds at the folder.

**Question 1**) Does Macbook have a feature to open folders by dragging files to folders pointing for a sec on a Folder to open them?

COLUMN VIEW-method
2) I try dragging files to the proper folder via the column view. But Apple for some reason does not show higher rank folders then the current folder. So I can not shift to other maps (since the "Download folder has no lower rank folders).

**Question 2**) Can I somehow view higher rank folders in Finder in the "folder view"?

CUT-method
3) I try to cut the files and don't want to keep files in the download folder. But for some reason Apple does not allow that. I only have the COPY option for somereason.

**Question 3**) Is there a way to make it possible to CUT file in the "Download Folder"? 
QUESTION IS ANSWERED BY wrecclesham.

I am used to moving files easily and visually comfortable in for example the browser version of Google Drive.

Comment: I believe that asking "Why Apple does ___" is considered off topic. As no one but the (famously secretive) Apple itself knows *WHY* it does something. Asking questions like that is unproductive. I hear your pain having worked on Macs since '89 I know of frustration...

Comment: Macs, contra to your rant, are very intuitive. What they are not is a copy of Windows. If you hold over your destination in the sidebar for a couple of seconds, it will spring open. If you don't & just drop to it straight away it will still move the files if they're on the same Volume, or copy if they're not. Hold Cmd to make it Move to a different Volume. [Apple provides extensive documentation for Windows switchers](https://support.apple.com/HT204216). Read it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, Windows or not. I am more used to Google Drive since I switched a lot between Apple and Windows. And Google Drive is very intuitive in moving files around by shifting the mousepointer with the appropiate file virtually to a new folder.

But well apparently I have to get used to opening in Finder windows to move a file from one folder to another with a mouse.

The Cmd-trick you mention I don't understand. It seems not to work. What do you mean with "Hold Cmd to make it Move to a different"?

Comment: "to a different volume". Your question still isn't really clear & seems to be 4 different questions. If you want proper answers, split each question to a different post & be clear about what you actually are trying to do. Your descriptions are far too vague. Bear in mind we cannot see over your shoulder what you're trying to do. Use pictures if you need, to better explain.

Comment: Your terminology is still hugely confusing. Shifting.. you mean moving/changing file location? Map.. directory/folder? Higher/lower rank.. directory hierarchy?  Cut has already been answered, but  you still have too many questions for one post. One post, one question & be clearer what you mean.

Comment: I mean moving a file with a mouse button held down. I don't know the word for it. Dragging I thing?

Answer (score 4):

You actually can cut and paste files on a Mac, it's just harder to find the option.

In Windows, you first choose either `Cut` or `Copy` as your first step and then use the same `Paste` command for both actions.

On a Mac, you choose the same `Copy` command as your first step but then have a choice of two possible shortcuts in order to perform either a `Cut/Paste` or `Copy/Paste` action.

**Keyboard shortcut:** ⌨️

1. `Copy` as you would normally, with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
2. `Paste` with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

In case you missed what's going on here: *including the `Option` key turns a Copy/Paste into a Cut/Paste!*

**Mouse:** ️

The `Move` option is hidden in the Edit menu but will appear temporarily while you hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the added value is of. Command + Option + V. Normally it is Command + V? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Did you _try_, @Joost?

Comment: As an aside: dragging files with the mouse/trackpad defaults to moving them; holding down Option while releasing the drag yields a copy/duplication instead.

Comment: @JoostFvanderLinden adding the Option key turns a Copy/Paste into a Cut/Paste. I've updated my answer to make this more obvious.

Comment: Thanks  wrecclesham! This works! Question three is now solved :-)